# Set input type text value after redirecting using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to fill a textbox value using JavaScript after a redirect is done. The scenario is the following:

The user clicks on a button, which will redirects the user to the contact page with a contact form. Then some contact textboxes like e.g. "subject" should already be filled. I'm using this code for my button:

```
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="RegisterCourse('test')" />
```

And this is my JavaScript code:

```
function RegisterCourse(title){
    window.location.href = "http://www.mydomain.ch/contact";
    document.getElementsByName("your-subject")[0].value = title; // your-subject is the textbox name
}
```

I think this isn't working because of the redirect. When I output `document.getElementsByName("your-subject").length`, it returns "0".

Is this even possible? If yes, how can I achieve this? If not, are there any alternatives?

Comment: You can certainly do it, The question is, what is your targeted browsers ? 
Based on that you can use several mediums to pass data along the redirection ( assuming the redirection is not to an external domain ) such as: cookies, local storage, session storage etc..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This cannot work, because after redirecting, the JavaScript

1. can't get executed anymore.
2. can't change a control on another page.

One idea could be to add a URL parameter to the redirect and then, on the new page, check for this URL parameter and if set, then set the control with this parameter value.

Comment: Okay, then I'll try PHP as @PetrCihlar said. Thx!